# Python 2.7 - Count number of items in Output

Tags: python-2.7

I need to count the number of items in my output. 
So for example i created this:

```
a =1000000
while a >=10:
    print a
    a=a/2
```

How would i count how many halving steps were carried out?
Thanks

Comment: store that in a variable during loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways: the empiric way and the predictible way.

```
a =1000000

import math
print("theorical iterations {}".format(int(math.log2(a//10)+0.5)))

counter=0
while a >=10:
    counter+=1
    a//=2

print("real iterations {}".format(counter))
```

I get:

```
theorical iterations 17
real iterations 17
```

The experimental method just counts the iterations, whereas the predictive method relies on the rounded (to upper bound) result of `log2` value of `a` (which matches the complexity of the algorithm).

(It's rounded to upper bound because if it's more than 16, then you need 17 iterations)

Answer (score 0):

```
c = 0
a = 1000000 
while a >= 10: 
  print a
  a = a / 2
  c = c + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Don't understand what you did there? Adding C = 0 and C++ at the end gave me a synthax error.

Comment: I edited the code. You can print c to find out the number of times a was halved.